# Create a list/sequence of numbers from two DOY in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, list

I would like to create a list of numbers from a DOY to another DOY every 7 days, dependent on a specific date that I set. This then matches an imageCollection I have, which I then use to create a weekly average.

So far I have this.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2015-01-01');

var start = ee.Date(startDate.advance(-2,'month'));
var end = ee.Date(start.advance(1,'year').advance(-1,'day'));

var sdoy = start.getRelative('day', 'year');
var edoy = end.getRelative('day', 'year');
```

I'm trying to use something like

```
var DOYList = ee.List.sequence(sdoy, edoy , 7);
```

But because `ee.List.sequence` doesn't know to go forward to 365 and back to the edoy, I'm producing a list without any numbers. Is there a way of telling `ee.List.sequence` to do this? Or another way of creating a list of numbers to use.

My code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjw1280%2FSTRESS_SCORE%3AReef%20health%20variables%2FDHW_NEW) and it's lines 111-118 in the code which are the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand correctly that you want to construct a list of DOYs? You can make a list of dates in milliseconds, and than map over that list and get the relative Day of the year from that. It also works for multiple years:

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2015-01-01');

var start = ee.Date(startDate.advance(-2,'month'));
var end = ee.Date(start.advance(1,'year').advance(-1,'day'));

var sdoy = start.getRelative('day', 'year');
var sMillis = start.millis();
var eMillis = end.millis();

var millisIn7Days = 7*24*60*60*1000;
var DOYList = ee.List.sequence(sMillis, eMillis , millisIn7Days).map(function(dateMillis){
  return ee.Date(dateMillis).getRelative('day', 'year');
});
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/0d7a42ce4915d2888f53442b14a72349)

Comment: works really well thank you!